# Finding a prime numbers between two very large range

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to find the prime numbers between Two numbers let say A and B `2<A B<10^8`
Here is my approach

```
public static boolean isprime(int a){

    for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(a);i++)
        if(a%i==0) return false;

    return true;
}

for(int i=A;i<=B;i++) if(isprime(i)) ans++;
```

If A=2 and B=10^8 it is taking very large amount of time How can i improve my algorithm.
Thanks

Comment: If this code works and you just need code review, then ask there: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Use a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @Tom yes it is a working code

Comment: Hint, hint, hint: java.util.BitSet + spider's comment

Comment: @BoristheSpider would you please explain me the method

Comment: Just look at the wikipedia page. It's demo is better than anything that can be provided here.

Answer (score 1):

Prime number is a positive natural number that has only two positive natural number divisors - one and itself. The opposite of prime numbers are composite numbers. A composite number is a positive natural number that has at least one positive divisor other than one or itself.

```
public class Question3 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                PrimeCount(10,30);;
    }

    public static int PrimeCount( int start,int end)
    {
          int count=0;
        if(start<0)
        {
            if(end > 2)
            {
                count ++;
            }
            start=0;
        }
        if(end < 0)
        {
            end=0;
        }

      for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
      {

         for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
         {

             if(i%j==0)
             { 
                 //count ++;
                 break;// innerloop;
             }
             else
             {
                 if(j+1==i)
                 {
                    // count ++;
                     System.out.println(i); //display the prime number
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     continue;

                 }
             }
         }
      }
    return count;//returns the count of prime numbers in the given range
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main loop from A+B, you can probe only numbers "6a +-1",
because of:

```
6a   - is not prime, divisible by 6
6a+1 - can be prime
6a+2 - is not prime, even
6a+3 - is not prime, divisible by 3
6a+4 - is not prime, even
6a+5 - 6(a+1)-1.
```

Thus, you can increase performance 3x times.

Also, function IsPrime() can try divide to 2, and thereafter iterate only odd dividers, with i+=2. This is also increase performance twice.

Thus, 6x performance increase is easy reachable without serious change your algorithm.

More efficient way - to drop non-prime candidates by little Fermat theorem:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem